# How to iterate throw typedef enum in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, enums

I'm developing an iOS application with latest SDK.

I have this enum:

```
typedef enum BoxTypeValues {
    Speed,
    FPS,
    Altitude,
    Location,
    Accuracy
} BoxType;
```

And I want to iterate throw all of its values and convert them to `NSString`.

I'm doing it this way, but it is very hard coded:

```
+ (NSArray*)BoxTypeValues
{
    return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Speed", @"FPS", @"Altitude", @"Location",
            @"Accuracy", nil];
}

+ (NSString*)BoxTypeToString:(BoxType)aType
{
    NSString* result = nil;

    switch (aType)
    {
        case Speed:
            result = @"Speed";
            break;
        case FPS:
            result = @"FPS";
            break;
        case Altitude:
            result = @"Altitude";
            break;
        case Location:
            result = @"Location";
            break;
        case Accuracy:
            result = @"Accuracy";
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Any advice?**

Comment: you are passing same name and storing it in string? what is the need for doing this?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your question.

Comment: You are switching for FPS and returning FPS,,,,, so there is no need to use switch case, simply return the string. isn't it?

Answer (score 6):

Converting an enum value to a string is one of the rare cases where macros can help a lot. For example:

```
- (NSString*)BoxTypeToString:(BoxType)aType
{
#define CASE(VALUE) case (VALUE): return @( #VALUE )
    switch (aType) {
            CASE(Speed);
            CASE(FPS);
            CASE(Altitude);
            CASE(Location);
            CASE(Accuracy);

        default:
            // should not get here
            assert(0);
            break;
    }
#undef CASE
    return nil;
}
```

Your `BoxTypeValues` method would then look like this:

```
- (NSArray*)BoxTypeStringValues
{
    return @[
        [self BoxTypeToString:Speed],
        [self BoxTypeToString:FPS],
        [self BoxTypeToString:Altitude],
        [self BoxTypeToString:Location],
        [self BoxTypeToString:Accuracy]
      ];
}
```

This will continue to work nicely even after refactoring operations rename the enum values. You may want to give the `CASE` macro some sort of unique prefix to avoid conflicts with other code.

As for enumerating the enum values, you're out of luck unless you can rely on the values being sequential and using a standard for loop (as others have suggested).

Comment: what does the hashtag in "@( #VALUE )" do?

Comment: It stringizes the argument, turning it into a C-literal, which is then boxed into an NSString inside the @().

Answer (score 2):

```
  + (NSString*)BoxTypeToString:(BoxType)aType{
    return [BoxTypeValues objectAtIndex:aType];
}
```

Just modify your method, no need to use switch-case.

Comment: and if you still don't want to create that hard-coded array, then use Dictionary instead of enum

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem multiple times. Everyone who saw java enums wants to have this functionality in Obj-C, too.

One of the solutions is to use a class instead of an enum. If you want to go with `enums`, there is a nice preprocessor technique called `X-Macros`.

Let's define the values first:

```
#define BOX_TYPE_DEFINITIONS \
    BOX_TYPE_DEFINITION(Invalid, = 0) \
    BOX_TYPE_DEFINITION(Speed,) \
    BOX_TYPE_DEFINITION(FPS,) \
    BOX_TYPE_DEFINITION(Altitude,) \
    BOX_TYPE_DEFINITION(Location,) \
    BOX_TYPE_DEFINITION(Accuracy,)
```

Now the enum

```
#define BOX_TYPE_DEFINITION(name, intValue) name intValue,

typedef enum {
    BOX_TYPE_DEFINITIONS
} BoxType;

#undef BOX_TYPE_DEFINITION
```

And "to string" function

```
#define BOX_TYPE_DEFINITION(name, intValue) [name] = @#name, 

NSString* BoxTypeStringTable[] = {
    BOX_TYPE_DEFINITIONS
};

#undef BOX_TYPE_DEFINITION

#define NUM_BOX_TYPES sizeof(BoxTypeStringTable) / sizeof(NSString*)

NSString* NSStringFromBoxType(BoxType type) {
    return BoxTypeStringTable[type];
}
```

This technique is very powerful for 3 reasons

1. If you want to add/remove values, you do it in one place only
2. You have the list of values as a macro and you can generate almost any code which involves all the values.
3. You can add other attributes to your enum values (are you sure you don't want to use classes?)

Answer (score 0):

If you control the enum and can make sure that it is sequential then you could just do the following - but obviously you now have to things to keep up to date now.

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, BoxType) {
  Speed,
  FPS,
  Altitude,
  Location,
  Accuracy
};

NSString * BoxTypeToString(BoxType boxType)
{
  static NSString *types[] = { @"Speed", @"FPS", @"Altitude", @"Location", @"Accuracy" };
  return types[boxType];
}
```

**NB**

I've made this a separate C function as I can't really imagine many scenarios that give a good reason for a class to be responsible for knowing how to convert an enum into a string :/